# Retrofit2 interceptor, using token only in specific methods

Tags: android, authorization, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

I want to use `authorization` in `Retrofit2`. I've choosen `interceptor` way because almost all methods require `authorization`, except one where I am geting token for further use with other methods.

My question is: **How can I achieve this?**

I store my access token in `SharedPreferences`. My first idea was: "*I can retrieve it in my `RetrofitClient` class and depending if token is null or it has value create suitable `Retrofit` instance*" (with or without adding `.client()` to it.

Unfortunately it's not that easy because `Context` is needed to get preferences.

I don't know how to pass it into `RetrofitClient` class or how to get to it inside.

Here's my `RetrofitClient` class:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private RetrofitClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                //.client(getRequestHeader())
                .build();
    }

    /*OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + )
        }
    })*/

    public static synchronized Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public Api getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

My `getRequestHeader()` is previous method where I was setting timeout.

I want to create instance like this:

```
private RetrofitClient() {
            tokenService.token = null;
            tokenService.readToken(ApplicationContext.getInstance());


            if (tokenService.token == null) {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
            } else {
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client(client) //I have interceptor here with access token
                        .build();
            }
        }
```

And then:
`RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(Api.class).getToken()` //getting Token
`RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(Api.class).someMethod()` //when I get Token
Is it good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use application context which is available while your app is live. Get it from your app class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp instance;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
    //other code
}
public static MyApp getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

And then simply use `MyApp.getInstance()` to get context where you need. With this approach you can achieve what did you think before and get SharedPreferences in `RetrofitClient` class.

Don't forget to add your app class to manifest.

UPDATE: 
You are creating your retrofit instance only once, so if you create it when you will have token - you will always use it, while app is alive.
I think, good practice is to check for token in your interceptor. Something like this:

```
new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();
            if (tokenService.token == null) {
                return chain.proceed(request);
            } else {
                return chain.proceed(request.newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + tokenService.token).build());
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, I don't know how your tokenService is working. But keep in mind, that the best is to always check in shared preferences for token, if you clear it there when logout. Because your tokenService may keep token string even if it is cleared in shared preferences.

Comment: And the last simple question. If i call `RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(Api.class).getToken()` and then `RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(Api.class).someMethod()` which requires token is it gonna behave well? Check modification of the constructor in my edit please.

Comment: @SkypeDogg I updated my answer, hope it is clear now

Comment: Class `TokenService` has one String field for token, and three methods: `saveToken()`, `readToken()` and `clearToken()` but everytime I turn on app I ask for token with PIN, but I use next methods, only If token comes back with code `200`, otherwise it informs about wrong PIN. Everytime new token comes back it overrides old PIN, so there shouldn't be any mistakes I hope, even without `clearToken()` method

Comment: @SkypeDogg great, hope I helped you a bit

Answer (score 0):

Simply add SharedPreferences as constructor parameter in RetrofitClient or other depending on situation

Answer (score 0):

You can do in following way:

First create a preference class with singleton instance

> Preferences

```
public class Preferences {

    public static Preferences INSTANCE;
    private final String PREFERENCE_FILE = "my_preferences";
    public final String PREF_TOKEN = "pref_user_token";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEdit;

    private Preferences() {
        Application app = MyApplicationClass.getInstance();
        mPrefs = app.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mEdit = mPrefs.edit();
    }

    // Returns singleton instance
    public static Preferences getInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null)
            INSTANCE = new Preferences();
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return Preferences.getInstance().mPrefs.getString(PREF_TOKEN, "");
    }

    public void saveToken(String value) {
        mEdit.putString(PREF_TOKEN, value);
        mEdit.apply();
    }

}
```

Then change in you RetrofitClient class as below:

> RetrofitClient

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private RetrofitClient() {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(mClient)
                .build();
    }

    OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + Preferences.getInstance().getToken())
        }
    })

    public static synchronized Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    public Api getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```